# I there a way to make Overleaf folded code stay folded after refreshing the page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, code-folding

I am working with lagre Tikz enviroments. It would be nice to have an option that keeps at least the axis folded in order to facilitate better navigation betweeen the different figures.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in overleaf, but making new .tex files for tikz code and adding them with `\input{bla.tex}` is an alternative.